# How to determine BT headset type (SCO or A2DP) in Android SDK?

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

I have a broadcast receiver in my app that logs every connection of a BT device by tracking the `android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED` broadcast. But I need to know if the BT device isa headset, and more importantly, if it's an SCO or an A2DP headset. I can find out what services the connected device supports using BluetoothClass.Service, but I don't know which services are supposed to correspong to each type of headset. Here are the ones listed:

```
AUDIO 
CAPTURE
INFORMATION 
LIMITED_DISCOVERABILITY 
NETWORKING 
OBJECT_TRANSFER 
POSITIONING 
RENDER 
TELEPHONY
```

Can anyone tell me which of these determiny the headset profile type (headset, hands-free, or A2DP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener and listen for onServiceConnetced and you will get notifications for A2DP or SCO connected.
See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener.html)

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned -- I need it to work on OS 2.0 and up (API 5), this one is API 11, so I have to do it the way I have it in the original post, just don't know which services belong to which profile

Comment: The above info only gives information if the device is capable of audio if the service has AUDIO in it.. there is no way to know which profile using the older public API. (It could be possible via private APIs)

Comment: OK, can I determine the protocol based on BluetoothClass.Device? It lists all the possible major & minor device classes, so is there a list of which clsses are SCO and which are A2DP?

Comment: No you cannot deterministically determine profile types - you can only guess, typically devices that can do A2DP can do Handsfree also ... so the device class will have both types .

Comment: So, back to my question -- how can I "guess"? which device classes correspond to which possible profiles? Do I need to see if a device has a specific combination of classes?